# How to fix Ruby error: `require': cannot load such file -Programing Ruby 1.9 & 2.0 4th edition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws-cloud9

This is my first post and I apologize for any errors in my formatting.

I'm using AWS cloud9 as my IDE. I am trying to load a file, however I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from gserver:9:in `<main>'
    1: from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- gserver (LoadError)
```

My gserver-logger.rb code is:

```
require 'gserver'

class LogServer < GServer

def initialize
  super(12345)
end

def serve(client)
  client.puts get_end_of_log_file
end


private

 def get_end_of_log_file
   File.open("/var/log/system.log") do |log|
     log.seek(-500, IO::SEEK_END)   
     log.gets                        
     log.read                        
     end
   end
 end

server = LogServer.new
server.start.join
```

I have verified that gserver is in the same directory and therefore my code should be able to access the file gserver-logger.rb. All of this is from the book, Programming Ruby 1.9 & 2.0 4th edition.pdf page 86.
Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You claim that the filename is `gserver-logger.rb`, but you are requireing a file named `gserver`. This can't be right.

Comment: Thank you for point this out. I've made corrections to ensure the names are correct. However I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gserver` used to be part of Ruby's standards library for some time. However, it [was removed from the standards library](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5480) with Ruby 2.2.0 since it was basically unmaintained and had no tests.

This (un-)maintenance status has not really changed since. If you still need the functionality of the library, you can install and use the [`gserver` gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/gserver) which contains the code state as it was removed form the standards library. However, I would strongly recommend to use something else instead...

Comment: Also you may want to use a more up-to-date book or at least take the considerations in your book with a huge grain of salt. The final version of Ruby 1.9 was released 6.5 years ago, the final version of 2.0 was released 5 years ago. A lot of things in a lot of areas have changed since then...

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I'm new to programing and trying to teach myself. I saw this book was recommended by Chris Pine with his "Learn to Program" book and thats why I started going through it. I will look for a more up to date book to study.